# How to install Minikube and kubernates on amazon Linux EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

Anyone having command to install minikube and kubernates on Amazon-linux . I have tried to some linux command but it's not working.

Thanks
Baharul Islam

Answer (score 3):

**kubernetes Installation**

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
EOF
yum install -y kubectl
```

**Minikube Installation**

```
curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 \
  && chmod +x minikube
```

To add the Minikube executable to your path:

```
sudo cp minikube /usr/local/bin && rm minikube
```

Sources: [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/#linux) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-linux)

**Make sure to remember that Amazon Linux is based on RHEL/CentOS**